# How do I make a luminescent gas cloud?

Tags: light, point-clouds

How can I make a luminescent gas cloud, similar to the one shown in the picture below (labeled "Trapped Atoms")? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Simple **Sphere** with **Emission** as a **Volume** would be sufficient. We will use for both methods mostly the same setup. **Gradient Texture** > **Color Ramp** > **Emission** shader.

**Color Ramp** will control color and smoothness.
**Emission** > **Strength**... Strength.

### Without Emission.

[image: without]

They will look like gas spheres and emission will not affect other meshes.

[image: node_1]

### With Emission.

[image: emission]

This ones will affect meshes with light.

[image: node_2]

Comment: Aw, beat me to it! Great answer, have an upvote. (:

Comment: Hi cgslav, I have tried using your method. However, when I increase the emission strength, the cloud goes back to being a solid sphere again. Do you know a method that works at all emission strength? Thank you.

Comment: @user3886914 than you will need to tweak color ramp to make it soft again.