# How to Make Highlights Glow

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor, add-on, compositing-nodes

I'm creating this scene with a "Star Wars" feel. And in Rogue One, The ships had this large highlight like the metal of the ships were glowing from the lit sides only. I'm also noticing some slight blue just on the outside of the main bright white. I've tried Emission nodes (not at all what I was looking for lol) and I've tried the Glare node in the compositor node sheet. And I can't seem to find what it is. Is there an effect or addon maybe to help me achieve this "Glowing" effect? Reference on what I mean below.

[image]

Comment: maybe try this kind of solution: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120563/how-do-i-make-a-luminescent-gas-cloud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'glare' for the bright parts should be able to be achieved with a Glare node in the compositor - set up the Threshold to ignore any parts that are not bright enough so as to get the effect on only the highlights.

However, for added configurability you could also add in the output of a Blur node as follows :

[image: Blur highlights]

Adjust the Glare node, the Value nodes, and the Blur settings as desired.

Note the Subtract Mix node set to 'Clamp'. This effectively removes all but the highlights - so you only get blur of the particularly bright sections. The Multiply after the Blur allows you to control the strength of the 'haze' around those highlights. The RGB node allows you to adjust the color, to bring up the blue, for example.

Here's another example - with the effect over-emphasised for clarity :

[image: result]

Comment: What were yourRGB Curves set to?

Comment: @PraxisVisuals Apologies - the RGB Curves node was an impractical way of adjusting the color (not sure what I was thinking with that). Now edited to use an RGB node to generate the color directly rather than trying to adjust the output of a Value node with curves. Adjust the strength of the blur by adjusting the 'brightness' of the RGB node and adjust the color to adjust the tint.