# How to get a lighthouse to shine a lightbeam

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

I was wondering how i can get my lighthouse to shine a clean and realistic beam.
I cant get my volume density low enough to get the desired result.
Do any of you know how to maybe get a volume emission to work like a gradient?
So that the light cone is less intense the further its away?

or can i add some invisible geometry that is in the way of the light but in all other respects transparent?
Light baking maybe?

Summin like this.
https://captainkimo.com/foggy-morning-jupiter-lighthouse-with-light-ray/
or dis.
https://twistedsifter.com/2013/07/pigeon-point-lighthouse/

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this node setup works not too bad:

- I've created a simple light ball for the light source, maybe you should add a bit of glow around as it's explained here: [How do I make a luminescent gas cloud?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120563/how-do-i-make-a-luminescent-gas-cloud)
- Now, for the beam, first, create a conic cylinder.
- For the length gradient, mix an *Emission* node with a *Transparent* node, use a *Gradient* as factor, and a *ColorRamp* to control its intensity.
- For the width gradient, mix the first *Mix Shader* with the *Transparent* node, use a *Layer Weight* as factor, and a *ColorRamp* to control its intensity.
- To add a bit of noise you could mix the previous nodes with the *Transparent* node, with a *Noise* texture as a factor.

[image]