# Need help trying to make a lighthouse lamp

Tags: animation, materials, shaders, lighting, photorealism

I was trying to make a lighthouse asset for a scene I was making and ran into a little roadblock.

I need some help trying to make the lamp which goes on the top. I was imagining a beam of light which rotates 360d in the sky.

I tried using a spot light, point light , area light and even emission mixed with transparent shader but nothing seems to work..

Blend File: https://pasteall.org/blend/23a7e321432143bba254149136d1161c

Thanks in advance. I really am stuck here

**My progress so far:**
[image]

**Lamp:**

[image]

Comment: if you're talking about the beam of light, you could try with volumetrics or you can try a trick with Layer Weight, see here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227887/how-can-i-make-cone-look-more-like-light/227889#227889 and here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134478/how-to-get-a-lighthouse-to-shine-a-lightbeam

Comment: Thanks. I too was thinking of using volumetrics but I think this trick will be sufficient too. Will definitely try it.

Comment: made some tests with eevee and cycles, result applied https://twitter.com/begalovr/status/1405637458570645509
at freetime can give complex answer